# Why Key Released function of swing in java it not giving appropriate result.?

Tags: java, swing

I have java project on payroll management system but when I try to search any id in search bar it says "missing data". My code has no errors.
I designed this code in netbeans 8.2 version.
I used xampp for database and core java for coding.
I have to submit it soon.
I have attached my table detail of databse.

```
private void txt_searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{

        String sql ="select * from staff_info where id=? ";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,txt_search.getText());
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

            String add1 =rs.getString("id");
            txt_id.setText(add1);

            String add2 =rs.getString("first_name");
            txt_firstname.setText(add2);

            String add3 =rs.getString("surname");
            txt_surname.setText(add3);

            String add4 =rs.getString("Dob");
            txt_dob.setText(add4);

            String add5 =rs.getString("Email");
            txt_email.setText(add5);

            String add6 =rs.getString("Telephone");
            txt_tel.setText(add6);

            String add7 =rs.getString("Address");
            txt_address.setText(add7);

            String add8 =rs.getString("Department");
            txt_dep.setText(add8);

            String add9 =rs.getString("Gender");
            txt_dep.setText(add9);

            String add10 =rs.getString("Salary");
            txt_salary.setText(add10);

            String add11 =rs.getString("Address2");
            txt_add2.setText(add11);

            String add12 =rs.getString("Apartment");
            txt_apt.setText(add12);

            String add13 =rs.getString("Post_code");
            txt_pc.setText(add13);

            String add14 =rs.getString("Status");
            txt_status.setText(add14);

            String add15 =rs.getString("Date_hired");
            txt_doj.setText(add15);

             String add16 =rs.getString("job_title");
            txt_job.setText(add16);

            String add17 =rs.getString("Designation");
            txt_desig.setText(add17);



            byte[] img = rs.getBytes("Image");
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img).getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl_img.getWidth(), lbl_img.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            lbl_img.setIcon(imageIcon);

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Missing Data");
    }
    finally {

        try{

            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

} 
          `
```

[image]

Comment: id should be of type Integer, you have written setString(), is that right?

Comment: Put a debug point one step after " rs=pst.executeQuery();" and the check for the value of rs, if its null, then no result, if not then again check your code

Comment: Also, I see the method has return type void and you are setting some properties of an object, are you returning something to your layer above your persistence layer ?

Comment: It clearly shows, ID is of type Integer, change your method name to  setInt()

Comment: 1) `catch(Exception e){

        }` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I always love "Help, I caught any exception and printed a message that doesn't tell me what's wrong instead. Now I'm getting that message and don't know what's wrong."

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` to detect changes to text components, `KeyListener` is generally a poor choice for this kind of operation

Comment: i m not understanding where i have to change code....please explain clearly@sForSujit

Comment: changing setString to setInt is giving error